# Combining data sets of different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My problem is next:

I have data frame A that looks like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

and data frame B that look like this:

```
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2
```

and I am trying to add B to A, so result should look like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

At the moment I am extending data frame B with zeros so size it gets equal in size with data frame A ..... and just sum those two data frames.

Is there more elegant way of doing this?
Also how I can add data frame B to the different parts of data frame A .... and for example will have result like this:

```
3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Let me know if my question is not clear :)

Thanks.

Comment: update with `dfA.iloc[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col] += dfB.to_numpy()`?

Comment: Excellent, it works :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first one :

```
A.iloc[2:4, 2:4] =  A.iloc[2:4, 2:4] + B.to_numpy()
```

and for the second one :

```
A.iloc[0:2, 0:2] =  A.iloc[2:4, 2:4] + B.to_numpy()
```